# bitmonerod/simplewallet tag renamming

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Since [bitmonerod](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitmonerod) and [simplewallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplewallet) will be named monerod and monero-wallet-cli respectively in the next release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is a good idea and something we should eventually do. Luckily creating [tag synonyms](https://monero.stackexchange.com/admin/create-tag-synonym) is pretty easy.

Because it will take a while before people become accustomed to the new names I see no reason to rush. We can allow both synonyms for some period of time before considering merging the old tags into the new ones.

Comment: Did you create a synonym, yet?

Comment: @5chdn Okay I just created/suggested both the monero-wallet-cli and monerod synonyms

Comment: Would "wallet-cli" make a better tag than "monero-wallet-cli" as a replacement for simplewallet?

Comment: While I typically prefer shorter ones, this case is different since it is an existing name, and as such chopping off one part makes it confusing